# How to automatically redirect to sign in after timeout in the client side with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, timeout

I'm trying to get my client side rails application to redirect to the sign in page when Devise times the user out.

We have periodic requests that get sent out every 30 seconds or so, so before this request, I'm trying to check if the user's session has expired. The issue with this is that the requests are sent via jQuery.

Inside devise.rb I'm overriding the timedout? method to try and set a session variable if the session is timed out.

```
module Devise
  module Models
    module Timeoutable
      def timedout?(last_access)
        # Custom code goes into this method
        session[:user_expired] = true
        !timeout_in.nil? && last_access && last_access <= timeout_in.ago
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my client side view home page (home.html.erb), I have the following method to get this session variable:

```
<script>
  fuction getExpired()
  {
    console.log("getExpired");
    var session_val = <%= session[:user_expired].to_json %>
    return session_val;
  }
</script>
```

Finally, in my JavaScript file that sends the requests, I will be calling this method and checking if it is equal or not equal to true.

The issue that I'm running into at the moment is "Caught NameError: undefined local variable or method `session' for #". Looking further into it, it seems you can only create session variables in controllers, which means I need another way of passing a value from this timedout? method to JavaScript.

I have also tried leaving the timedout? method as is and done the following in home.html.erb

```
<script>
  fuction getExpired()
  {
    console.log("getExpired");
    var timedOutVar;
    <% if current_user.timedout?(1.second.ago) %>
      timedOutVar = true
    <% else %>
      timedOutVar = false
    <% end %>
  }
</script>
```

This doesn't seem to be working though, as timedOutVar is always == false. It seems that the ruby code is not executed inside of the function apart from when the script is first generated. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy because Devise is server side, and the client don't take care about session expiration.

But this gem could help you :

[auto-session-timeout](https://github.com/pelargir/auto-session-timeout)

it will add some Javascript helper to logout after inactivity.

Hope it works :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AhmeDEV , but we're trying to keep gem usage to a minimum for our application. I'll keep looking around for alternatives!